# Es posible realizar una redirección enviando datos?

Tags: laravel-5

He intentado realizar una redirección desde un método POST a un método GET, pero no se si es posible enviar la dirección con datos, es posible?

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function listado()
{

    $usuarios=usuarios::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
    $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
    return view('usuario.listado',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones')); 

}


  /**
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function selector(Request $request)

    {
        $tipo = $request->tipo;
        $usuarios=usuarios::where("user_id","=",$request->tipo)->paginate(10);
        $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        return redirect()->route('usuario.listado')->with(compact($usuarios, $usuariosOpciones));


    }


  /**
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function cedula(Request $request)

    {
        $cc = $request->cc;
        $usuarios=usuarios::where("cedula","=",$request->cc)->paginate(10);
        $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        return redirect()->route('usuario.listado')->with(compact($usuarios, $usuariosOpciones));
    }
```

Quiero que el metodo selector y cedula envien datos al metodo listado.

Comment: Practicamente haces lo mismo en todas tus funciones... porque redireccionar con datos? porque no solo retornar a la vista?

Comment: Por que al retornar la vista quedo en la ruta POST, y al recargar la pagina tengo un error, la unica forma de evitar ese error es redireccionar  a una ruta GET.

Comment: si lo hago asi funciona, como tu dices.   https://paste.laravel.io/a887182f-1ba4-48d4-8c85-07ceae6a8260, el problema es que queda en la ruta http://crudgobernaciontres.test/panel/selector que es POST en vez dehttp://crudgobernaciontres.test/panel/selector que es GET

Comment: En realidad no entiendo porque las peticiones son distintas si ambas hacen lo mismo

Comment: Bueno me equivoque... las que es GET debe ser http://crudgobernaciontres.test/panel/listado, pero a pesar de que hace la consulta correctamente queda en la ruta crudgobernaciontres.test/panel/selector que es POST, si recargo la pagina ahi es donde aparece el error, por que en esa ruta supuestamente envio datos no consulto.. por eso necesito que quede el resultado en la ruta GET

Comment: No seria mas fácil hacerlo por ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues la verdad tu forma de hacer las cosas son un poco equivocas, te recomiendo lo siguiente en tu función listado, que debe de ser la del método `get`.

```
public function listado(Request $request)
{
    $usuarios=usuarios::orderBy('id','DESC');
    if($request->has("tipo")){
        $usuarios=$usuarios->where("user_id","=",$request->tipo)
    }
    $usuarios=$usuarios->paginate(10);
    $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
    return view('usuario.listado',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones')); 

}
```

Y tu html quedaría algo asi:

```
<form action="{{url('listado')}}" method='get'>
    <select name="tipo">
        <option>op1</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y asunto arreglado

Comment: Si amigo... tienes toda la razon, con el get en el formulario se arreglo.. se que aun no programo en laravel de manera clara, apena estoy empezando.. muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar datos en una redireccion,utilizas el controlador y elmetodo,de esta manera:

```
return redirect()->action(
'UserController@listado', 
['usuarios' => $usuarios,'usuariosOpciones' => $usuariosOpciones]
);
```

de esta menera seras redireccionado al metodo listado y enviaras las variables como un array.